# Disabling a certain ObjectiveC task?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, delegates

First, a bit of nomenclature clarifying:

In ObjectiveC "event handlers" are defined through delegates. And a delegate may have multiple tasks, is this naming scheme right?

Now the actual question: if a delegate has for example 6 tasks, can I disable at runtime having one of those tasks called without dettaching the whole delegate?

I have a task that is called around 30 times a second and would like to disable it unless explicitly desired. I haven't benchmarked it tho, maybe it isn't consuming as much CPU as I fear, but anyway, my question stil stays just to satisfy my curiosity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to use NSNotification's - read the documentation of [`NSNotificationCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

Delegates are necessary part of any action and added as they are needed. If you have not implemented a particular delegate method it will not be called. If implemented with no code in it it will take a single CPU cycle and thus it will not create a CPU overhead so there is no need to explicitly disable any delegate.

If you don't need simply don't implement that delegate method in your class. Only implement the methods you need and have code in it.